# Altering the files of a rails application without restarting the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application running on production environment on a remote server. Though the application is ready for use it is far from finished so it is going to be subject to changes in views, controllers and css files.

Is there a way to update one of those files and make the server aware of the change without having to stop it? I tried cleaning the caches on both server and browser side in order to force the application to regenerate them with no success.

In the `production.rb` file I have these options

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.log_level = :fatal
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered versioning with [Git](http://git-scm.com/)?  In a typical rails deployment, you would use something like git to version your software and then deploy with something like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) so that you can push small changes up to a place like [Github](https://github.com/) and then pull those changes in to your app via capistrano.  There's a really great tutorial on how to do this on railscasts by Ryan Bates.  Here's a link to [Railscast #335](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems I need to do some studying. Will get back with the results.

Comment: @avlach - did you have any luck?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the time but I was forced to stay off my computer for some time...
So I synced with git successfully.
I installed capistrano.
I made capistrano create releases synced with git.
But I can not make it run any command and I can not find any documentation.
I will share some more info with you in case you can help me.

I am using jruby 1.7.10 (1.9.3p392) and I deploy using puma.

`jruby -S puma -d`

My problem is in the `deploy.rb` in this section

`namespace :deploy do
desc "Restart application"
task :restart do
#What do I write here? <-----
end
after :finishing, "deploy:cleanup"`